# Show $f, g\in\mathscr{L}^2(\mu)$ imply $f\overline{g}, \overline{f}g\in\mathscr{L}(\mu)$, and $\int f\overline{g} +\overline{f}g\leq2\|f\|\|g\|$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

The problem arises from Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*:
[image]

**My Question**:

1. The equality highlighted in yellow. Indeed we have $\|f+g\|^2=\int|f+g|^2d\mu=\int(|f|^2+f\overline{g}+\overline{f}g+|g|^2)d\mu$; but in order to say $\int(|f|^2+f\overline{g}+\overline{f}g+|g|^2)d\mu=\int|f|^2+\int f\overline{g}+\int\overline{f}g+\int|g|^2$, **we need to have $\mathbf{f\overline{g}, \overline{f}g\in\mathscr{L}(\mu)}$ first**. To that end, we let $f=u+iv$, and let $g=a+ib$, then $\int|f\overline{g}|d\mu=\int\sqrt{(ua+vb)^2+(va-ub)^2}d\mu$. But then I failed to show that $\int\sqrt{(ua+vb)^2+(va-ub)^2}d\mu<+\infty$.
2. The inequality highlighted in green. In order to say the inequality holds, **we must have  $\mathbf{\int f\overline{g} +\overline{f}g\leq2\|f\|\|g\|}$**, which I again failed to show.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Schwarz inequality,
$$\int|fg| \leq \|f\|\|g\| < \infty$$
In particular, as $|\bar{f}g| = |f\bar{g}| = |fg|,$ this shows $\bar{f}g, f\bar{g}, fg \in \mathscr{L}$.  This should resolve your first question.

---

By the triangle inequality in $\mathbb{C}$,
$$\begin{align*}\|f+g\|^2 &= \left|\|f+g\|^2\right| \\ &= \left|\int|f|^2 + \int f\bar{g} + \int \bar{f}g + \int|g|^2\right|\\ &\leq \int |f|^2 + \left|\int f\bar{g}\right| + \left|\int\bar{f}g\right| + \int |g|^2\end{align*}$$

And by theorem 11.26,
$$\left|\int f\bar{g}\right| \leq \int|fg| \\ \left|\int \bar{f}g\right| \leq \int|fg|$$

Putting it together:
$$\|f+g\|^2 \leq \|f\|^2 + 2\int|fg| + \|g\|^2.$$

Again, by Schwarz, $$\|f+g\|^2 \leq \|f\|^2 + 2\|f\|\|g\| + \|g\|^2$$

Comment: @Brain Moehring I appreciate the answer! However, I must say that "$\begin{align*} \left|\|f+g\|^2\right| \\ &= \left|\int|f|^2 + \int f\bar{g} + \int \bar{f}g + \int|g|^2\right|\\ \end{align*}$" is precisely my first question.

Comment: I am still sort of confused what you're having trouble with. Is there an issue with $|f\overline{g}| = |fg|$ that I am not seeing? This should follow immediately from that and Schwarz inequality if I am not mistaken. You just note that $$\int |f\overline{g}| = \int |fg| \leq \|f\|_2\|g\|_2 < \infty.$$ This is why I suggested what I wrote in my answer

Comment: Also, I just looked at your other post, and this is included in the Schwarz inequality screenshot that you posted

Comment: @DickGrayson CalabiYau's first comment here answers that.  The Schwarz inequality shows directly $f,g \in \mathscr{L}^2 \implies fg, |fg|, \bar{f}g, f\bar{g} \in \mathscr{L}$.

Comment: @DickGrayson I've rewritten the answer to make the order of the logic more clear

Comment: @BrianMoehring I appreciate the help! Indeed, $|\bar{f}g| = |f\bar{g}| = |fg|$ was the identity I did not know.

Comment: @CalabiYau I appreciate the help! I now see what you meant by Schwarz inequality-I guess I was too tired last night when I posted the comments...

Answer (score 1):

The $L^2$ inner product is generally defined as
$$\langle f,g \rangle_{L^2(\mu)} = \int_X f\overline{g}d\mu.$$
Then recall that for a general inner product, we have $|\langle u,v \rangle| \leq \|u\|\cdot\|v\|$. I think this is what you were missing. Can you fill in the rest?

Comment: I appreciate the hint! However, I do not intend to use the properties of inner products-I believe the results can be shown using just the definitions and earlier theorems.

Comment: He tells you to use the Schwarz inequality, which is what that property is

Comment: The Schwarz inequality is $\int |fg|d\mu\leq\|f\|\|g\|$, if $f,g\in\mathscr{L}^2(\mu)$, which is the theorem right before this one.